# Get notifications from comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I find myself adding more comments than answers in an attempt to help the OP's improve their questions.

One would get notifications of responses only if the commenter (either the OP or other user) would `@ping` the username.

Often times, new users in particular, do not know they need to `@ping` commenters back and requires me to track back questions to monitor for a eventual response.

This is clearly unpractical and consumes time that could be better.

My feature wish is to have some form of "smart subscribe" to a question that would notify me of comments that could be potential responses to my intervention. Ideally it would pop in the inbox, but maybe be labeled different to indicate that it's a suggestion rather than an explicit. 
Or it could be as simple as a "subscribe" button (but not RSS. Who uses that these days?)

Comment: @Glorfindel you are right. I missed that one while browsing to similar questions asked before.